# Where is the new SonarQube Gradle Plugin?

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, gradle-plugin, sonarqube-scan

Having recently upgraded from a previous version of Gradle, I started getting a warning that I should use the official SonarQube plugin:

> The 'sonar-runner' plugin has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 3.0. please use the official plugin from SonarQube ([the docs](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/gradle.html)).

From that link, I was directed to the Gradle Plugins page for the new plugin (https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube), which tells me to use:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:1.2"
  }
}

apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
```

But that fails. The error I'm seeing in my Gradle output is:

```
Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/sonarsource/scanner/gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/1.2/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-1.2.pom'.  
> peer not authenticated
```

When I try to access the same location through a browser, I get a 404, and if I browse the file structure from https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org, I can go as far as https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/sonarsource/scanner/, but the only subdirectories I see there are 'ant', 'cli' and 'maven', no 'gradle'. Presumably this is the root cause of my problem.

From other questions on here, I can see that others are using the plugin, so presumably it's available somewhere, but I can't find it. Any suggestions on a working source?

Comment: Would you mind just trying it again? If I try to request `https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/sonarsource/scanner/gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/1.2/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-1.2.pom` from the browser it is delivered fine. Maybe there was a short temporary outage?

Comment: This url: https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/sonarsource/scanner/gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/1.2/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-1.2.pom works fine for me. Maybe you're experiencing network issues? Firewall/proxy etc?

Comment: You're right, that does work, thank you. It's highlighted that my problem is actually in my Artifactory repo failing to find the plugin. Rather than confuse this question, I've asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553930/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-is-not-found-by-artifactory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We got the plugin into Gradle by adding

> classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:1.2"

to buildscript dependencies. We then added

> apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'

to activate it. Our local Artifactory instance is set up to proxy jCenter and mavenCentral.