# SonarQube Gradle Plugin is not found by Artifactory

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, artifactory, gradle-plugin, sonarqube-scan

(This question elaborates on a [a question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550576/where-is-the-new-sonarqube-gradle-plugin?noredirect=1#comment60702524_36550576), but with enough differences that I think it warrants a separate question)

[This post on the Gradle forums](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/cant-apply-org-sonarqube-plugin-when-using-artifactory-cache/12541) describes similar symptoms, but not quite the same as my problem.

Like the poster there, I get the error:

> Plugin with id 'org.sonarqube' not found.

when trying to use the SonarQube Gradle plugin with the following in my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url 'http://[artifactory-url]:8081/artifactory/plugins-release/' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:1.2")
  }
}

apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
```

He says that his instance of Artifactory has cached the plugin, whereas mine hasn't. Similar to him, I'm behind a corporate firewall, and have no admin rights on Artifactory, but I can see that the `plugins-release` virtual repo does include both    https://plugins.gradle.org/m2 and http://jcenter.bintray.com. Ordinarily, simply requesting a library from our Artifactory server makes it find and cache that library immediately, but in this case it is clearly failing.

When I remove the `apply plugin...` line, I see the following error:

```
   > Could not find org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:1.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
     file:/C:/Users/[username]/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/1.2/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-1.2.pom
     file:/C:/Users/[username]/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/1.2/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-1.2.jar
     http://[artifactory-url]/artifactory/plugins-release/org/sonarsource/scanner/gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/1.2/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-1.2.pom
     http://[artifactory-url]/artifactory/plugins-release/org/sonarsource/scanner/gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/1.2/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-1.2.jar
```

So, I'm fairly sure that Artifactory is failing to find and cache the plugin. If I browse to https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/sonarsource/scanner/gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/1.2/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-1.2.pom, I can get to the POM file, and the same for the JAR file, but I notice that if I browse to https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/sonarsource/scanner, it doesn't include 'gradle' as a subdirectory. I don't know if that's relevant, but perhaps that's the cause of the problem I'm seeing with Artifactory?

I'm not sure whether to raise this as a bug against the plugin, or if it's an Artifactory issue, or simply some kind of misconfiguration on our side. Any thoughts much appreciated!

### Update with trace

Thanks to @drorb I got a trace from Artifactory, and found:

> 2016-04-12T10:28:40.918+01:00 Executing HEAD request to https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/sonarsource/scanner/gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/1.2/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-1.2.pom
>   2016-04-12T10:28:40.924+01:00 Received status {} (message: 501) on remote info request - returning unfound resource

501 is 'not implemented', so I assume this is telling me that the plugins.gradle.org repo doesn't support HEAD requests, which seems to mean Artifactory can't query it properly. I'm surprised that it works for others though - perhaps there's some Artifactory config I can get changed to not do the HEAD request?

### Further update with cause, but not really an answer

Further digging made me realise that the HEAD request *does* in fact give me a proper response (303 which leads to a 200), so I think the issue is connectivity from our Artifactory server. This doesn't seem worth adding as an answer, but I'll leave it here in case it helps someone else experiencing similar issues.

Comment: I would start by running a trace request in Artifactory. This should give you more information about what Artifactory is trying to do in order to resolve the file from the virtual repository. In your case the trace request should be for http://[artifactory-url]:8081/artifactory/plugins-release/org/sonarsource/scanner/gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/1.2/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-1.2.pom?trace

Comment: I tried simulating your HEAD request as follows:
> curl -I https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/sonarsource/scanner/gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/1.2/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-1.2.pom
The result was 303 See Other, and a forward to Location: https://gradleware-plugins.s3.amazonaws.com/org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/1.2/f49f0cec239bbce6e950c8ed76e92eb904010d73b43e2b586dc95018638d3253/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-1.2.pom

Rerunning with curl -IL followed the redirect succesfully. 

Do you have an old artifactory? Or perhaps it's too locked down to be able to redirect?

Comment: Ah, sorry - I thought I'd added a further update, but clearly didn't submit - I see the same thing doing a HEAD through PostMan on my machine, so it must be some firewall/proxy issue here. I've raised the appropriate request so will keep my fingers crossed... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet of our Gradle conf, which works:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://[artifactory-url]:7980/artifactory/libs-release"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:1.2"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
```

The only difference I can see is that we put /artifactory/libs-release in the maven url, while you have /artifactory/plugins-release. Perhaps you should try pointing to libs-release, and see if that works?

Comment: Thanks - good suggestion, and I tried it but with no luck. I can see from the trace suggested by @drorb that it's trying to download it from plugins.gradle.org but getting a 501 when it does a HEAD request. Not sure what to make of that...